# Button Click on Enter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik, enter

I have several panels in my page,and each panel has a submit and clearall buttons.
I am trying to set focus of enter to my submit button.

I have an image button in my logo,and everytime user hits enter,its downloading file on imageclick.

Can someone suggest how do i set focus of enter to my submit button.Any ideas?

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="100%" ForeColor="Black" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">

     <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  TabIndex="1" OnClick="OnSubmitClick" CausesValidation="true" />

       <telerik:RadButton ID="btnclearall" runat="server" OnClick="OnClearAllClick"        CausesValidation="false" />

      </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer without using forms or panel?

Answer (score 0):

try `defaultfocus` attribute in `<form>` tag ,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultfocus="btnSubmit" >
```

Comment: I don't have a form tag,using <asp:Content>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the UseSubmitBehavior attribute?

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  TabIndex="1" OnClick="OnSubmitClick" CausesValidation="true" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
```

Set the other buttons to false. Technically you shouldn't have to set UseSubmitBehavior to true since it is default but setting all others to false might help.